# Spring Injection of resource fields failed

Tags: java, spring

I have a `BaseDAO` and some subClass eg:`UserDaoImpl`,`OrderDaoImpl`,now in a `BaseService`

```
public abstract class Baservice{

    @Resource
    private BaseDao basedao;
    //something crud operate.....
}

@Service
public UserService extends BaseService{
   //....
}
```

how to configure Spring that I can pass a real subclass to basedao

I encount a exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of resource fields failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.cloudking.trafficmonitor.BaseDAO] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: [roleDAO, userDAO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have 3 classes which extends `BaseDAO` so all of them are `BaseDao` (IS A)

You need to use `name`  attribute of `@Resource`

For example:

```
@Component
public RoleDao extends BaseDao{/* some code*/}
```

and

```
@Component
public UserDao extends BaseDao{/* some code*/}
```

now if you want to inject `UserDao` then

```
@Resource(name="userDao")
BaseDao baseDao
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Qualifier("UserDaoImpl")`

or use `@Resource(name="UserDaoImpl")`

Answer (score 0):

Your application is unable to find the bean BaseDAO. You need to annotate BaseDAO with
@Component (or @ Service, not sure about this one)